# python 3.6.3: backspace, arrow keys not working properly

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, build, python-3.6

I recently installed python 3.6.3 in a linux machine at my workplace. I compiled it from source. When I enter the python shell, the backspace and arrow keys are not working properly. They are displayed as some sort of escape characters.
If it helps, following is the result of running the `make` command

```
Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel
_dbm                  _gdbm                 _lzma
_sqlite3              _ssl                  _tkinter
readline              zlib
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

The python 2.6 version installed on the same system is working properly.
python 2.6 is installed in the location `/usr/bin` and python 3.6.3 is in the location `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: You'll need to install the header files for readline and recompile, as described in some of the answers in the duplicate linked.